# Flutter camera plugin, get path before recoding stopped

Tags: flutter

I'm using [camera plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/changelog) to record video. However, I need this video to be transferred to API. I want to do that in chunks, lets say 4MB. I would usually do this with a loop reading file size to check when we have new chunk. The problem is that from version `0.6.0` and above `startVideoRecording()` no longer accepts path where to store it and I don't know where the file is to keep reading its size. It only gives the path after the recording is stopped. That means I have to start transferring after that and this would be annoying for the user.

I know I can downgrade my version below `0.6.0` but I really don't want to do that if there is another way.

So, is there a way to get current file being recorded after `startVideoRecording()` is called?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.  I just started looking at how to capture video and all the examples are either not compiling or have this path commented out so I'm very confused what their state is of development.  I get things are in flux, but how can you remove the only way to get the path to the captured video?

Comment: you have access to the camera controller where in you can listen to it and collect the video bytes and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on the github refactor open issue, just FYI.  Looks like they will look at adding it as an optional parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you use this lib for help to pickup and capture video or image and get full path and file Object
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Not sure how this helps me, I need video path before video recording is stopped.

Comment: you min you have alrady assign video path before recording ?